# IOS animating subviews as app launches?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I'm simply trying to animate in some uiviews,

- first I'm removing the subviews out of the screen bounds in `viewWillAppear`
- then I'm moving them back in place using `UIView.animate` in `viewDidAppear`

`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  label.center.x -= view.bounds.width
  username.center.x -= view.bounds.width
  password.center.x -= view.bounds.width
  login.center.x -= view.bounds.width
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  print("view did appear")
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    self.label.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    self.username.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    self.password.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    self.login.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
  }
}
```

what is it that I'm doing wrong?

### edit 1

when I comment either the `viewDidAppear` it has no effect on the views whatsoever.  ( they are in place as in the storyboard )

Comment: You'r doing very good keep it up. But what is the issue?

Comment: When you say “as app launches” do you mean you’re trying to do this in the launch screen?

Comment: @dahiya_boy its not working, actually when I comment `viewDidAppear` the views don't move at all.

Comment: @Fogmeister no I mean the app launches they are not there then over 1 second they animate in from the side.

Comment: Are you using auto layout constraints to set their position in your storyboard? 

If so you'll need to animate the constraint values otherwise auto layout will keep them in place.

Comment: @tomsterritt yes I am using constraints , I believe that might be the issue , thanks.

Comment: @tomsterritt ineed that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Aeid, I would like to offer an alternative solution that allows you to animate **whether you have constraints or not**, if I might.

## Grouping

I notice you are moving 4 UI elements. I might suggest you group them all together into one UIView (with a clear background color). That way you only have to animate one UI element.
[image: One UIView]

## Animation

One of my favorite ways to animate an object is to "transform" it. There are 3 transforms you can apply:

1. Rotation
2. Resizing (called "Scale")
3. Repositioning (called "Translate")

Every UI object has a `.transform` property. You apply a transform using `CGAffineTransform`. (CG = Core Graphics, Affine = preserving parallel relationships. Rotating, Resizing and Reposition doesn't skew or warp the object)

## Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginView: UIView!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        loginView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -view.bounds.width, y: 0)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.loginView.transform = .identity // Remove the transform
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animated Login]

## Advantages

- It doesn't matter what constraints are on the object. It will work.
- You only don't have to reposition twice, only one time. Then remove the transform to have it go back to its original position.

Comment: I know how to use  `CGAffineTransform` (from your yt channel --thanks by the way-- ) it is similar to css3 transforms. but I've just picked an animation book and I was wondering why this example was not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside that animation closure.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
    self.label.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    self.username.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    self.password.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    self.login.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did try that but the code inside `viewWillAppear` was not executing, so it animated the views out of the screen to the right, 

it was actually due to `constraints`.  ( removing constraints solved the issue )

Comment: @aeid "removing constraints solved the issue" NO! why you remove constraints?? Just keep them and animate the constraints, that is the way you should animate views... Do not animate the frame itself.

Comment: @J.Doe thanks, noted,  however I've just started learning about IOS animation.